Creating a materialized view based on calling web service in Oracle Apex
Is it possible to create a materialized view in Oracle Apex based on a web service call? I'm trying to make an API request and use its JSON response directly in a materialized view, but I'm getting an error.
Create  materialized view mat_view 
      BUILD IMMEDIATE
  REFRESH FAST ON STATEMENT WITH PRIMARY KEY
as
select region_id, region_name 
from ( 
SELECT region_id, region_name
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    (SELECT APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST(
                P_URL => 'https:blablablablablablabla',
                P_HTTP_METHOD => 'GET'
           ) AS X FROM DUAL),
    '$.items[*]' COLUMNS (
        region_id   NUMBER  PATH '$.region_id',
        region_name VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.region_name'
    )
));

I'm getting the error ORA-32368: cannot create JSON materialized view without relational table at line 13/30. Is there any way to work around this, or am I missing something in the syntax? I'd like to refresh the data in the view based on this API response, but it seems like Oracle requires a relational table for a materialized view. How can I achieve this functionality?

Try with a standard table that you update with a MERGE statement, assuming region_id is unique. The only drawback is that you will need to handle to delete of disappearing ones in a separate statement.

I can't see how that can be anything except a REFRESH COMPLETE materialized view. There won't be any such thing as an mview log and presumably the web service is giving you a complete set of regions each time.
Also, check out APEX automations - I'm pretty sure it has facilities to materialize the results of a webs service all within APEX.
